# Why use GC.SuppressFinalize() when there is no Finalizer?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

As the question states, I just wanted to know, because I've been asked and I don't have a clue, is there any reason for this whatsoever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a class does not define a Finalizer (destructor), a call to `SuppressFinalize()` on an instance of that class [has no effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

When you see it, it usually is a left-over of  the full Disposable implementation. Just remove it or ignore it.

Comment: If a class does not have a finalizer, `GC.SuppressFinalize()` is equivalent to `GC.KeepAlive()`.  As such, it will not only disable the class's own finalizer from running, but will *ensure that the finalizers of any objects to which it holds references won't get scheduled for execution until disposal is complete*.  It won't guard against finalizers running "early" if an object gets abandoned without disposal, but will guard against premature finalization of the objects it owns in cases where the object gets properly disposed.

Comment: @supercat are you saying that if anything in the object graph fails to dispose or finalize, then the entire graph will remain memory?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: When an object that is eligible for finalization is to have no references to it other than a special list of objects eligible for finalization, it is "eligible for finalization" flag is cleared but it is moved to a strongly-rooted list of objects that should be finalized at earliest convenience.  Just before launching the finalizer the object will be removed from the latter list, so if no other references to the object get created, it will become eligible for collection on the next cycle.

Comment: @supercat - your top comment here could do with a reference to some  source.  I simply don't get it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: An object can't be destroyed until there's no way any running code will ever acquire or hold a reference to it.  If running code has or could acquire a reference to X, and X contains a reference to Y, the system will assume that running code could acquire a reference to Y.  As long as there exists a possible execution path where `GC.SuppressFinalize(X)` will be called, code will need to keep a reference to X so it can be passed to that method (implying that object X must continue to exist until then).

Comment: Hmmm, that would be true for any reference. SuppressFinalize is not special in nay way. And as it's usually called from Dispose() I can't see how it would be relevant.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Suppose `Foo` holds the only strong rooted reference anywhere in the universe to an object `Bar` which has a finalizer, and the finalizer of `Bar` would have some side-effect upon object `Boz` that would be detrimental to the operation of `Foo`.  If the last thing that will ever be done with a reference to `Foo` is to call a method which acts upon `Boz`, then in the absence of a `GC.KeepAlive` or `GC.SuppressFinalize`, the system could start running the finalizer of `Bar` while the function is still using `Boz`.  Adding either of the `GC.*` calls would ensure that can't happen.

Answer (score 3):

The reason might be to prevent potential error if someone adds a finalizer later on and forgets to add `GC.SuppressFinalize()`.